# Getting the type of a TypedArray in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typed-arrays

I'm using the following code to get the actual data type of a TypedArray in TypeScript

```
type BufferElementType =
    | "float"
    | "uint8"
    | "uint16"
    | "uint32"
    | "int8"
    | "int16"
    | "int32";

function getBufferElementType(buffer: ArrayBufferView): BufferElementType {
    const name = (buffer as any).__proto__.constructor.name;
    switch (name) {
        case "Int8Array":
            return "int8";
        case "Uint8Array":
            return "uint8";
        case "Int16Array":
            return "int16";
        case "Uint16Array":
            return "uint16";
        case "Int32Array":
            return "int32";
        case "Uint32Array":
            return "uint32";
        case "Float32Array":
            return "float";
    }

    throw new Error(`Unsupported buffer type ${name}`);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way without using `(buffer as any).__proto__.constructor.name;`

Comment: At a minimum, you can (and should) remove the `.__proto__` part of that. You don't need to go to the prototype, and if you did, `__proto__` (a browser-only extension) isn't a best practice way to do it, `Object.getPrototypeOf` is. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for clarification. I was actually just clicking through the object hierarchy in the console of my browser to find what I need and copied it to my code.

Comment: You shouldn't tag this question with typescript though, because you can't typecheck at runtime, it's just that some object (like the ones in your example are actual types of arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.__proto__.constructor.name;` you can use `instanceof` to check:

```js
function getBufferElementType(buffer: ArrayBufferView): BufferElementType {
    if (buffer instanceof Int8Array) {
        return "int8";
    } else if (buffer instanceof Uint8Array) {
        return "uint8";
    } // etc...
}
```

Alternatively, if the check shouldn't include subclasses, you may compare the `.constructor` directly:

```js
if (buffer.constructor === Int8Array) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously that was to obvious for me ;-)